# How to verify AWS SigV4 signing

Tags: python

I have a server that will receive request with Authorization header which is SigV4 and based on verification of SigV4, I will grant the access of data. How do we verify SigV4? I have been trying to get the doc for verifying SigV4 but could not get it? Is there any way to de-compile the signing and check for authentication and then authorize?

Comment: This should be a good start: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-signed-request-examples.html -- you can also try using `HmacAuthV4Handler` directly from `botocore`

Comment: I know the signing process of SigV4 but what are the things that one needs to check to confirm the authentication of source? Is there a process that I can follow for un-hashing the signature and verify? I will look into HmacAuthV4Handler.

Comment: To verify the signature, you generate the signature on your side and compare to the signature that arrived from the client.

Answer (score 0):

The [Sigv4 signing algorithm](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-calculate-signature.html) is

```
kSecret = your secret access key
kDate = HMAC("AWS4" + kSecret, Date)
kRegion = HMAC(kDate, Region)
kService = HMAC(kRegion, Service)
kSigning = HMAC(kService, "aws4_request")
```

This uses an [HMAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC). An HMAC uses a shared secret rather than an asymmetric public/private key.

Therefore, to verify the signature, your server needs to know the secret key of every client, or at least the `kSigning` derived by binding that secret to a specific date, region, and service.

This has the drawback that a server capable of verifying requests from any (client, date, region, service) is also capable of generating and signing new requests as that identity. Depending on your architecture, that may be a problem, if the server is not more trusted than all its clients.