# Validate AWS SIGv4 signature in Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-api-gateway, amazon-iam

We have a serverless backend which is protected by IAM in API Gateway. We have another in-house authentication solution and we want to support both Authentication mechanisms in our service. I was planning to write a Custom Authorizer with authentication chain supporting multiple Authentication.

However, I couldn't find any way to validate AWS Sigv4 signature on backend. I found AWS docs on how to sign a request or calculate Sigv4 signature ([1], [2], [3] and [4]), however all these docs are from client perspective in which client will have access to ACCESS_KEY_ID, SECRET_ACCESS_KEY and SESSION_TOKEN. When custom authorizer lambda will receive the request it'll have only ACCESS_KEY_ID (in Authorization header) and SESSION_TOKEN (as additional header). So re-calculating signature on backend is not possible. How can I validate the signature at the backend to authenticate?

This post might be a duplicate of [How to verify AWS SigV4 signing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40347917/how-to-verify-aws-sigv4-signing) which is still unanswered. [Solution suggested](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-signed-request-examples.html#sig-v4-examples-get-auth-header) in this question still need SECRET_ACCESS_KEY.

[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sig-v4-authenticating-requests.html
[2] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sig-v4-examples-using-sdks.html
[3] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signing_aws_api_requests.html
[4] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4_signing.html

Comment: As part of the signing process, the secret key is fed into a hmac algorithm.  To verify, one must rerun the signing process and verify the signatures match.  You can't do this without the secret key.

Comment: By any chance do you know how API Gateway do it? Somehow it validates the signature, right?

Comment: It must have access to the secret key on some level, probably done by handing off the request to a component that has that information, but can never return it, just validates the signature (and returns what it calculated .. since the error message AWS sends back will include it's expected signature)

Answer (score 0):

(Caveat: I'm talking out my ass a bit here and haven't tried to implement this myself, just going off first principles.)

My understanding is that SigV4 is symmetric crypto, since it's using HMAC which is symmetric. That implies that there's no way for your lambda (an untrusted 3rd party) to verify the signature without having the key itself (in this case, the "secret access key"). If you had that key, well, you'd be able to impersonate that user. Probably undesireable :P

With a session token, [you have to include the session token in a request header, as you mentioned](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-add-signature-to-request.html) (probably because otherwise no one could tell which session token you signed it with; there's no corresponding `AWS_SESSION_TOKEN_ID`). That means you actually could verify the signature, but only the request's *integrity*: you don't know if that session token actually belongs to the user in question.

So I think you're hooped unless AWS verifies it for you.